# submit button on an ajax popup does not work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, button, popup

i have an ajax popup like this...

```
<div class="white-popup-block" style="max-width:600px; margin: 20px auto;">
<?php
include "konekdb.php";
if(isset($_GET['kode_kb'])) {
    $kode_kb = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['kode_kb']);

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM  kb_tiny 
                         WHERE kode_kb='$kode_kb'" ;
        $query = mysql_query($sql, $koneksiDB) or die ("error query".mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo "Title : ".$data['title'];
        echo "No Ticket :".$data['no_ticket'];
        echo "Error Code : ".$data['error_code'];
        echo "example :  ".$data['ex_case'];
        echo "Solution :".$data['solution'];
        echo "Creator :  ".$data['creator'];
        echo "Date Modified :  ".$data['modified'];

}
?>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input name="approved" type="button" value="Approved" /> <input name="reject" type="button" value="Reject" />
</form>
</div>
```

when i clicked detailed on my select * database, it show popup like above, when it popup it offer button to approve and reject...
how to process that button, so it could update my database status...
something like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['approved'])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE `kb_tiny` SET `status` = 'approved'";
```

please help me how supposed the code to work... 
the data already showing but approved button and reject not working :(

Comment: Is the button supposed to be of type button?

Comment: no it supposed submit button, and i missed that little detail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to process your button just change its input type ..

`<input type="button" />` **TO**

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
<input name="approved" type="button" value="Approved" /> 
<input name="reject" type="button" value="Reject" />
```

**To**

```
<input name="approved" type="submit" value="Approved" /> 
<input name="reject" type="submit" value="Reject" />
```